# Maximum call stack exceeded (recursion)

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am confusing the hell out of myself and I cannot get rid of this maximum call stack error.

Pretend the boxes variable is 100x larger. I just shrunk it down for demonstration. I don't know why it is doing this, I double checked my code a billion times and tried many different ways

```
let terminals_010617 = `YMMU6072258 Y773
YMMU6082317 Y773
YMMU6125912 Y773
YMMU6136250 Y773
YMMU6149895 Y773
YMMU6154464 Y309
ZCSU2601485 H798
ZCSU2656908 H798
`;





const REGEX = (function () {

    const RAW_CONTAINER_SEARCH = function (string) {

        let reg_newline = /\n/gi;  //       ---- USE THIS
        //let reg2 = /[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\n/gi; // off for temporary --- needs more testing

        let container_house = []; // will house the container+terminals

        let index_traveler;  // traverses between container+terminals ----  will first hold END of slice value, then BEGINNING of next
        let index_traveler2; // 
        let condition;

        container_house.push(string.slice(0, string.search(reg_newline))); // initiates the first container + terminal
        string = string.slice(string.search(reg_newline), string.length); // new string is after slice index

        GET_ALL_CONTAINERS();
        function GET_ALL_CONTAINERS() {
            condition = reg_newline.test(string);  // boolean
            index_traveler = 0
            index_traveler2 = string.search(reg_newline); // this will grab fresh index of index_traveler every loop

            while (string.length > 200) {
                container_house.push(string.slice(index_traveler, index_traveler2)) // grab container + terminal
                string = string.slice(index_traveler, string.length);
                GET_ALL_CONTAINERS();

                if (!condition) {
                    break;
                }

            }


        }
        console.log(container_house);
    }


    const ADD_TO_WL = function () {
        console.log('hello');
    }


    return {
        search_raw_containers: function (string) {
            RAW_CONTAINER_SEARCH(string);
        },
        add_to_wl: function (containerArray) {
            ADD_TO_WL(containerArray);
        }
    }

}());


REGEX.search_raw_containers(terminals_010617);
```

Comment: `index_traveler` is always `0`, so the value of `string` never changes. `"foo".slice(0,3)` returns `"foo"`. Since the value of `string` never changes, the condition of the `while` is always `true`. Therefore you haven infinite loop that makes a recursive call. Not sure what to suggest as solution since you don't explain what you are trying to achieve with all of this.

Comment: Im trying to cut each 16 lines from the string, so everytime it calls the function in the recursion it basically subtracts 16 characters. So when the length of string is around less than 15 then the loop ends. I'll edit my code in a bit for better clarification

Comment: I was thinking index_traveler should always be 0 because i was attempting to make the string's new value to be the rest of the string that is uncut on each iteration. Because the string's new value 0 will always be the start of the next 16 characters. Is it correct?

Comment: The only place you are "changing" `string` is in `string = string.slice(index_traveler, string.length);`. And as I said, that doesn't do anything. It's equivalent to `string = string;`. The length of the string won't change, so the loop never terminates. So, no, that's not correct, which is why you get that error.

Comment: How should I approach this in fixing it to make recursion execute until the end?

Comment: If you want `string` to become shorter then you actually need to make it `shorter`. So, pass the "right" arguments to `.slice`? I don't know what to suggest because I find the recursion in the `while` loop too confusing.